# Redirect to a specific page after Wordpress registration

Tags: wordpress, redirect, registration

I'm trying to get Wordpress to re-direct to a specific page after someone registers but not having much luck.

On other suggestions I have tried adding this to the functions.php file:

```
function __my_registration_redirect() 
{
    return home_url( '/page' );
}
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', '__my_registration_redirect' );
```

This did not work.

People also suggest using Peter's Login Redirect plugin, but it hasn't been updated in years and I can't get it to work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any headers problems, if you did not know turn on the debug log in wp-config

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

then try your code again and check the error log on wp-content/debug.log

Comment: Turned on debug and went through registration process but no debug.log appeared, so I assume no errors.